# blender grease pencil / Krita workflow question

Tags: grease-pencil

I'm a newbie currently researching the feasibility of grease pencil for 2d animation, I'm curious on how the author in this video https://vimeo.com/160449173

Can anyone tell me how this person open the animation in krita. It looks like he just painted one frame and it automatically carried the painting to different frames while still recognizing the position of the painting for each frame. How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To open a grease pencil animation in Krita, you first render the animation as a OpenGL animation. This will give you a sequence of images. Then you open Krita and start a new project with the same dimensions(or not) as your animation. Then you select File>Import animation frames and select the image sequence.

As for the painting, the author painted on a separate layer and used the Transform Layer brush with the Liquify option to manipulate the painted layer to stay with the animation. There is also an auto-frame option to keep changes per frame.

Comment: This are awesome features! I'll check it out! Thank you very much!